# How to bind label.textProperty() to tableView.selectedItem() in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have some problem with understanding bindings in JavaFX.
For example I use simple class Person for showing data in TableView.

```
public class Person {
    private StringProperty name=new SimpleStringProperty();
    public Person() {
    }
    public Person(StringProperty name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
}
```

I have PersonDataModel class too

```
public class PersonDataModel {
    private ObservableList<Person> personObservableList= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Person> singlePerson=new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Person());

    public void listInitialize(){
        personObservableList.clear();
        personObservableList.add(new Person(new SimpleStringProperty("John")));
        personObservableList.add(new Person(new SimpleStringProperty("Mike")));
        personObservableList.add(new Person(new SimpleStringProperty("Ana")));
    }
    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonObservableList() {
        return personObservableList;
    }
    public void setPersonObservableList(ObservableList<Person> personObservableList) {
        this.personObservableList = personObservableList;
    }
    public Person getSinglePerson() {
        return singlePerson.get();
    }
    public SimpleObjectProperty<Person> singlePersonProperty() {
        return singlePerson;
    }
    public void setSinglePerson(Person singlePerson) {
        this.singlePerson.set(singlePerson);
    }
}
```

And now I want bind label.textProperty() with selected item in tableView.I use controller class.

```
public class PersonWindowController {
    private PersonDataModel personDataModel=new PersonDataModel();
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> nameTableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> nameTableColumn;
    @FXML
    private Label nameLabel;
    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        personDataModel.listInitialize();
        nameTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData->cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        nameTableView.setItems(personDataModel.getPersonObservableList());
        nameLabel.textProperty().bind(personDataModel.getSinglePerson().nameProperty());
        nameTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue!=null) {
                //1. Option doesn't work
                //personDataModel.setSinglePerson(newValue);
                //System.out.println(personDataModel.getSinglePerson().getName());
                //2. Option works
                personDataModel.getSinglePerson().setName(newValue.getName());
                System.out.println(personDataModel.getSinglePerson().getName());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why first option doesn't work ?. I changed singlePerson object but nameLabel didn't change.
   I don't want to set all properties one by one when Person class will be more complicated. How to avoid this ?.
2. When singlePerson in PersonDataModel is just an object of Person class not SimpleObjectProperty the programm behaves exactly the same. Is any advantage to use SimpleObjectProperty in my example ?

Sorry for all mistakes I've made. Thanks in advance for your help.
Greg

Edit1: I edited my question after user Kleopatra answer.

Comment: I think [this page by Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/tableview.html) is perfect to learn how to use `TableView` (at least it has been useful for me).

Comment: [mcve] please .. including the _so on_ ;) From your snippet, the Person constructor looks wrong: don't use properties as params, instead pass-in the value. That said: you bind the label to a path property, that is the name of the singlePerson - now whenever the singlePerson changes (as it does when changing the selectedItem), the binding of the label must be updated to the nameProperty of the newly selected singlePerson.

Comment: repeating: you have to update your model's singlePerson __and__ the label binding on change of selectedItem. Without doing so, the label is still bound to the previous singlePerson: naturally not updated (bullet 1) or you change the name of the previous singlePerson (bullet 2)

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. I use binding to avoid setText on each label and be more ellegent. In my opinion of course. Thank you for your help.